# How can I set IgnoredErrors in ClosedXML to prevent warnings in Excel 'the number in this cell is formatted as text'

Tags: .net, excel, closedxml

I have DataTable with a string column with values that happen to look like numbers "0009.0" (accountants, go figure). I create an xml file based on this DataTable using ClosedXML `.Worksheet.Add(table)`. When I open an spreadsheet in Excel I see warnings for these cells "the number in this cell is formatted as text". In Excel I can ignore these warnings on a cell by cell basis and save the sheet. Using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool, I see this is stored in /docProps/core.xml:

```
<ignoredErrors>
   <ignoredError numberStoredAsText="1" sqref="A3 A5:A7" />
</ignoredErrors>
```

I'd like to know how to add this using ClosedXML.

I did find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66179979/600299) for how to do this with OpenXML (which ClosedXML wraps) but can't connect the dots.

Comment: ClosedXML doesn't implement this yet. We welcome pull requests for new features, though.